# GWT map error display grey area

Tags: google-maps, gwt

I have created a widget to display google earth and when I click the button, **google earth disappears and is replaced by google map**.

I am using the `gwt earth 3` and  [gwt map v3](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-maps-api/). When I click the button the first time, google map is display well.

But when I click the button again, google map is displayed very small inside a grey area like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383044/error-in-gwt-mapwidget), which used gwt-map v2.

In [gwt map v3](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-maps-api/), it doesn't have method `checkResizeAndCenter()`. So I want know if there is another way to fix this error.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you had situation like,map widget get added to a panel having width and height greater than width and height of map widget.